# Как картинку растянуть, чтобы она не следовала своим пропорциям в Access?

Tags: access, ms-access, access-control

[image: как]

Как картинку растянуть, чтобы она не следовала своим пропорциям в Access? Просто при растягивание фото, она пропорцианально увеличивается, а мне нужєно чтобі он была чуть растянута верх, подскажите где это можно сделать

Comment: А тянуть надо не за угол, а за середину стороны.

Comment: а как растянуть картинку, если она есть фоном для формы?

Comment: А какая разница? или ты реально думаешь, что для каждой картинки там свой особый ресайз?

Comment: капец вы  токсик